# Validation response property name is PascalCase instead of camelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this simple model with properties in PascalCase as default convention in C#:

```
public class ItemUpdateModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "descriptionText")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string DescriptionText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "priceUpdate")]
    public double? PriceUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

When i return the result from ModelState i get the properties/fields presented in PascalCase like this:

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "PriceUpdate",
      "message": "The priceUpdate field is required."
    },
    {
      "field": "DescriptionText",
      "message": "The descriptionText field is required."
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() in the startup.cs with no result.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding pascal case and camel case  this i not pascal  case ! do you mean  to be Pascal Case in response ?

Comment: Sorry if the example is single words and not concatenated, but I believe you got my question anyway.

Comment: are you using webapi or  webapi core  because camel case in the latest is by default ?

Comment: I'm using webApi core. And the normal responses from the API is camelCase and ok. It's only the validation result fields that are PascalCase.

Comment: and that 's correct because the model state follow the c# convention which is  pascal case

Comment: Yes, I understand that's the case. But is there any way I can change it? Because on the client side I want it to be camel.

Comment: how you have done  CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() show us because asp.net webapicore has a lot of breaking changes

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel This is how I did it, in Startup.cs

`services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters(o =>
                {
                    o.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });`